# ¿Es posible traducir los datos de una propiedad de una consulta a una API?

Tags: api

Estoy utilizando una API de cócteles. La mayoría de los cócteles cuentan con un campo llamado "strInstructions" que devuelve los datos en inglés, pero también existe un campo "strInstructionsES" que proporciona las instrucciones en español.

> strInstructions :  "In a shaker half-filled with ice cubes and combine
> the light rum."
>
> strInstructionsES :  "En una coctelera llena hasta la mitad con
> cubitos de hielo y mezcla el ron blanco.

Actualmente, estoy filtrando los cócteles utilizando este último campo, pero no todos los cócteles incluyen información en él; en la mayoría de los casos, este campo está vacío (null). Esta limitación restringe la cantidad de cócteles que puedo consultar. Por esta razón, me gustaría saber si existe alguna forma de traducir automáticamente el contenido del campo al español.

Comment: Una opción es utilizar una API de traducción para traducir la respuesta del inglés al español como Google da una prueba gratis https://cloud.google.com/translate?hl=es, también hay otras APIs más.